# Eyes as second mesh not following head as first mesh

Tags: mesh

My problem is this:

I made a fox and rigged the head which moves perfectly.
I made a second mesh for the eyes which are rigged perfectly.

BUT I can't manage to 'glue' the eyes to the head so that when I move the bone of the head the eyes move with the head!

Any idea? Cant find anything with google.

Best,
jb

Comment: "I made a second mesh for the eyes which are rigged perfectly" > Are you sure the eyes are correctly parented to the head bone? You have to check out in Weight Paint mode.

Answer (score 0):

Join the objects and armatures together as one object and one armature, then parent the eye armatures to the head.